# Is there a way to set a default app for Heroku Toolbelt?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have more than one app/git remote at heroku and I would like to know if it is possible to configure a default application so that, whenever I forget to specify the app (`--app`), the toolbelt would use it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can set the `heroku.remote` key in your repo's Git config to the name of the default remote. For example, if your remote is called `staging`, you could do this:

```
$ git config heroku.remote staging
```

To see how this works, here is the [relevant source](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/bb173f17625b396215ffc2996b97b385565ac53c/lib/heroku/command/base.rb#L178-L198).

For more, information about this, see [Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments).

Comment: Answer with source, nice! If I could double vote, I would do it.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what this should do?  I was expecting this to allow me to use heroku toolbelt CLI without having to specify `--app`. It's not working for me:

Comment: @denishaskin Would you mind to paste `git remote -v` results?

Comment: this is an awesome solution

Comment: The current Heroku CLI seems to set git remote name `heroku` as default (ref. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-a-new-heroku-app). So many users should set `heroku` instead of `staging` (i.e. `$ git config heroku.remote heroku`). The remote name can be checked by `$ git remote -v`. If the output is like this: `git-remote-name https://git.heroku.com/your-heroku-app-name.git`, you should type `$ git config heroku.remote git-remote-name`.

Comment: @denishaskin I was having the same issue, and fixed it by running `git config heroku.remote heroku` and then `heroku git:remote -a <app-name>`

Answer (score 44):

You could also go for:

```
heroku git:remote -a <name-of-the-app>
```

or if you tend to make a lot of mistakes in the configuration of wrong apps, you can use this library I made: https://github.com/kubek2k/heroshell

This is a Heroku wrapper shell that allows you to work in the context of a given Heroku application

Comment: This is the answer that actually sets the default Heroku app, so you don't have to keep specifying '-a'

Answer (score 33):

You can set the `HEROKU_APP` environment variable.

Found this question while searching for it myself. The other answers refer to Heroku's old ruby-based CLI. The new JS CLI doesn't seem to support the same git-remote-reading feature. A quick search of the source code on GitHub found [this](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/38c41e7df0fc8c8bc61ac6948723f02615388f06/packages/autocomplete/src/commands/autocomplete/options.ts#L133).

Comment: This worked for me to set the default app for Heroku CLI in order to avoid specifying the -a or --app parameter in all commands.